# How could I make two different layers of QML and a QGraphicScene in the same MainWindow (or similar) so that the QML?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I'm trying to make a "paintbrush" application using a custom toolbox made in QML and a QGraphicScene managed in c++. Practically I can choose tool by clicking on button on the QML toolbox and use it to draw something on the QGraphicScene.

I tried this way:

```
//MainWindow.h
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        MainWindow() {
           scene = new Scene(this);
           scene->setSceneRect(0, 0, 1920, 1200);

           QQuickWidget *quickwidget = new QQuickWidget();

           quickwidget->setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
           scene->addWidget(quickwidget);

           view = new QGraphicsView(scene);
           setCentralWidget(view);
        }

    private:
        QGraphicsView* view;
        Scene* scene;
};
```

```
//Scene.h
class Scene : public QGraphicsScene
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(Enums::Mode sceneMode READ sceneMode NOTIFY sceneModeChanged)

public:
    Scene(QObject* parent = 0);

    Enums::Mode sceneMode() const { return m_sceneMode; }
    Q_INVOKABLE void setMode(Enums::Mode mode);

signals:
    void sceneModeChanged();

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);

private:
    Enums::Mode m_sceneMode;
    QPointF origPoint;
    QGraphicsItem* itemToDraw;
    QPointF startPoint;
    void makeItemsControllable(bool areControllable);
};
```

```
//Main.qml 
Item {
    width: 1920
    height: 1200

    ColumnTopLeftButtons { id: topLeftButtonsColumn }
    ColumnTopRightButtons { id: topRightButtons }
    ColumnBottomLeftButtons { id:bottomLeftButtons }
    BarTopPanels { id:topPanelsBar }
    RightPanel { id: toolbox }
}
```

Making so, I'm drawing the QML on the scene obtaining that any action I make on the buttons of the panels or toolbox are taken from the scene as an input.
But, if I make to different objects, one for the scene and one for qml, also setting coordinates for each other to see one over the other (I prefer the scene under the tools), they appear placed side by side. 
So, how can I "isolate" input on toolbox respect the scene (that will not be always in use) or how can I have two different layers for both the qml tools and the scene?

Comment: You are trying to mix 2 different incompatible technologies. QGraphicsScene is a QWidget and QML is [Qt Quick Scene Graph](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-visualcanvas-scenegraph.html). You actually can trickly link them in C++ using maybe signals or whatever but that absolutely senseless task.

Comment: Yes, ok, I take note about it. But I have to do something similar. Maintaining the QML part as UI part, what could/should I use to have the drawing board as result (just like paintbrush)?

Comment: Why not to use QtQuick for all? [QQuickItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#details) is basically the same thing as `QGraphicsItem` i.e. it allows painting but using OpenGL instead of `QPainter`. If you still want to use `QPainter` use [QQuickPaintedItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickpainteditem.html).